# How to delete masked edittext content

Tags: java, android, masking

for example: "2020/55" I have an edittext shape, put one after 4 numbers, write a number after it and it works well. My problem starts at the time of deleting. When deleting the part after /, it shows"/////" the figures of the part before / as and instead.I add your picture, how can I delete it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0K8jH.png)

And mask class

```
public class CaseInputMask implements TextWatcher {
int uzunluk = 0;
EditText girilenMetin;

public CaseInputMask(EditText girilenMetin) {
    this.girilenMetin = girilenMetin;
    this.girilenMetin.addTextChangedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    String metin = girilenMetin.getText().toString();
    uzunluk = metin.length();
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    try {
        String metin = charSequence.toString();
        String girilenDeger = girilenMetin.getText().toString();
        if (girilenDeger.length() == 4) {
            metin += '/';
            girilenMetin.setText(metin);
            girilenMetin.setSelection(metin.length());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check deletion like this:

```
public class CaseInputMask implements TextWatcher {
private boolean running = false;
private boolean deleting = false;
private final String inputMask = "####/##";

public CaseInputMask() {

}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {
    deleting = count > after;
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    if (running || deleting) {
        return;
    }
    running = true;

    int length = editable.length();
    if (length < inputMask.length()) {
        if (inputMask.charAt(length) != '#') {
            editable.append(inputMask.charAt(length));
        } else if (inputMask.charAt(length-1) != '#') {
            editable.insert(length-1, inputMask, length-1, length);
        }
    }

    running = false;
   }
}
```

And

```
girilenMetin.addTextChangedListener(new CaseInputMask())
```

Comment: Is there a problem. I tried this code. It works fine.